# while adding new fields using doctrine showing PDO exception error

Tags: php, sql, zend-framework, doctrine-orm

this is a part of my code . when i first created the fields employee
    and type...it works perfectly...but i tried to add the third field
    it showing this error.please help me to find the error

```
    ----------
```

Doctrine error showing

```
      [Doctrine\DBAL\DBALException]                                                
      An exception occurred while executing 'ALTER TABLE leave ADD days VARCHAR(1  
      00) NOT NULL':                                                               

      SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error i  
      n your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server v  
      ersion for the right syntax to use near 'leave ADD days VARCHAR(100) NOT NU  
      LL' at line 1                                                                






      [PDOException]                                                               
      SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error i  
      n your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server v  
      ersion for the right syntax to use near 'leave ADD days VARCHAR(100) NOT NU  
      LL' at line 1                                                               

    ----------
```

THis is my Model.Leave.php

```
    <?php

    namespace Application\Model;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;

    /**
     * @ORM\Table(name="leave")
     * @ORM\Entity
     */
    class Leave extends Entity
    {
        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
         * @var string
         */
        protected $employee;


        public function getEmployee()
        {
            return $this->employee;
        }

        public function setEmployee($emp)
        {
            $this->employee = $emp;
        }

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
         * @var string
         */
        protected $type;


        public function getType()
        {
            return $this->type;
        }

        public function setType($type)
        {
            $this->type = $type;
        }

        /**
         * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=100)
         * @var string
         */
        protected $days;


        public function getDays()
        {
            return $this->days;
        }

        public function setDays($days)
        {
            $this->days = $days;
        }

    }
```

Comment: *"leave"* is a [reserved word](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) and Doctrine is not quoting it as an identifier. Are you sure you're using Doctrine 1.2? I don't think 1.2 has annotation support or namespaces

Comment: @Phil : thanks i changed leave.and it works good now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#quoting-reserved-words

You need to quote reserved words, eg

```
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="`leave`")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
```